# Is <regex> library working correctly?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I have the following easy example: where `<regex>` library is used to search "llo" in "hello world".

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    cout << boolalpha;
    regex rgx("llo");
    cmatch result;

    cout << regex_search("hello world", result, rgx) << endl;
    cout << "Matched: " << result.str() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it with "gcc version 4.7.1" with the following command:

```
c++ regex2.cpp -o regex2 -std=c++11
```

And the result is:

```
false
Matched:
```

So, what is supposed I am doing wrong? Since it compiles, can I assume that `c++11` is able on my computer and therefore  library is able too?

Sincerely thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No, `std::regex` is *not* fully implemented in the standard library implementation that comes with GCC 4.7.1.

Full support for `<regex>` will be released with **GCC 4.9** later this year.

See this: http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html

In the meantime, I recommend [`<boost/regex.hpp>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) using similar syntax.

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    boost::regex rgx("llo");
    boost::cmatch result;

    std::cout << boost::regex_search("hello world", result, rgx) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Matched: " << result.str() << std::endl;
}
```